# Content security policy report only in Firefox

Tags: firefox, content-security-policy

I've created a [content security policy](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html) for our sites, but i'd like to trial it first to see if it will cause any problems so I've used the report only header and added a report-uri directive.

The header name X-WebKit-CSP-Report-Only works correctly in Webkit based browsers, but neither X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only or [Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#report-only) work in Firefox (version 15). X-Content-Security-Policy works, sending violation reports to the URL specified in my report-uri directive. However, this also implements the policy which I don't want to do yet. Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: The header name "x-content-security-policy-report-only" should work fine as far as I can tell....

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work in Firefox 14 or 15.

Comment: Hmm.  Are you basically seeing something like https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687086 ?  Or are you seeing lack of reports for policies other than inline-script and eval-script?

Comment: Yes, that answers that question. Thanks Boris.